# Riverpod how to use "select" to filter rebuilds

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I want to use the `select` method in riverpod to avoid unnecessary rebuild, but there are some problems.My project only relies on flutter_riverpod: ^0.14.0+3, not hooks_riverpod. code show as below:

**UserProvider**

```dart
final userProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<UserNotifier>((ref) => UserNotifier());

class UserNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  String name = "jack";
  int age = 20;

  void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**Userpage**

```dart
class UserPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const UserPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Test'),),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Consumer(
            builder: (context, watch, child) {
              String name = watch(userProvider).name;
              return Text(
                'name is $name',
                style: TextStyle(color: randomColor),
              );
            },
          ),
          Consumer(builder: (context, watch, child) {
            int age = watch(userProvider).age;
            // ERROR! ERROR! ERROR!
            // int age1 = watch(userProvider.select((provider) => provider.age));
            return Text(
              'age is $age',
              style: TextStyle(color: randomColor),
            );
          })
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              var provider = context.read(userProvider);
              // setName
              provider.setName('Jack${Random().nextInt(10)}');
            },
            child: Text('Name'),
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              var provider = context.read(userProvider);
              // set age
              provider.setAge(Random().nextInt(100));
            },
            child: Text('Age'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How to use the `select` method in `Consumer` widget. Because what I want is that when the value of name changes, only the widget related to the name will be rebuilt, and the widget of age will not be rebuilt

Comment: Because my version is wrong, I changed it to version `flutter_riverpod: ^1.0.0-dev.7`, this method can be used.